# TeXworks symbol finder

Tags: symbols, texworks

Unlike most other TeX editors, TeXworks dose  not provide any facilities to find and insert symbols, is there any plugin or any program that can be used in parallel with TeXworks?

I am looking for a program like [''IPA Typing Assistant''](http://www.palsoftwaredesigns.com/ITA.htm) but for math symbols.
 It can be used for inserting IPA symbols in all applications easily.

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html and this question is a duplicate, please take a look here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol .

Comment: It is because TeXWorks philosophy is different from any other TeX editors that you have seen. Its main objective is to be simple and easy to use. Anyway, you should know all the symbols by heart.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Thanks, this is not a duplicate, I am looking for an application not a method for finding symbols in Internet.

Comment: @Reza The main idea is that it takes longer to hunt through menus than to type directly the symbol. You learn the symbols' names just by using them.

Comment: @egreg You are right, but I should know name of a symbol before typing it and I do not know all of them!

Comment: @Reza: You should then make use of "The Comprehensive LaTeX symbol List": http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: As well as you do not need the names of symbols to draw them in detexify.. Also a good start is to learn the greek alphabet by heart.

Answer (score 3):

It is because TeXWorks philosophy is different from any other TeX editors that you have seen. Its main objective is to be simple and easy to use.

If you're really looking for such a feature in a TeX editor, maybe your best bet would be to switch (at least temporarily) to one of these other editors.